# QNetworkAccessManager issue using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt

AM trying to develop an application using qt and visual studio. In my application, I want to access network, but using QNetworkAccessManager I got an error like `'Cannot open include file: 'QNetworkAccessManager': No such file or directory'`. How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

[QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) is a class from network module of Qt, so in order for you to use that class you'll need to add it's headers to include path and link to the network module library.

To do that (for a Qt module) in Visual Studio:

- open `Qt VS tools` menu
- open `Qt project settings`,
- in the dialog that appear you need to open `Qt Modules` tab
- check the `Network` module checkbox and confirm with `Ok`

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022, after clicking on Extensions -> Qt VS Tools -> Qt Project Settings, Click on these when the menu dialog appears

[image: In Visual Studio 2022, after clicking on Extensions -> Qt VS Tools -> Qt Project Settings, click on these when the menu dialog appears]

Then click on `Network`

[image: Then click on Network]